# Checking bit in byte not working

Tags: java, android

Checking bit value should be easy, but it doesn't work. In LogCat shown binary value

This was working and just stopped...

```
//test is byte received
//test = 3F binary: 00111111    
boolean b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,b6,b7,b8;

      b1 = (test & 1) !=0;
      b2 = (test & 2) !=0;
      b3 = (test & 4) !=0;
      b4 = (test & 8) !=0;
      b5 = (test & 16) !=0;
      b6 = (test & 32) !=0;
      b7 = (test & 64) !=0;
      b8 = (test & 128) !=0;
```

LogCat

```
11-06 10:58:58.455: D/Right panel(23660): 1        2        3       4       5       6       7       8
11-06 10:58:58.455: D/Right panel(23660): false    false    false   false   false   false   false   false
11-06 10:58:58.455: D/Right panel(23660): Data from handler: 003F binary1: 00111111
```

Comment: And what is that logcat supposed to show?

Comment: 1. What is test value? 2. Shift should be 0, 1, 2... Bit mask should be 1, 2, 4, 8 ... Don't mess them.

Comment: test is byte(binary 00111111).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guess that's what you want:

```
public static void main(String[] arg)
{
      boolean b[]=new boolean[9];
      int test=0x01f;

      b[1] = (test & 1) !=0;//(test & 1) !=0;
      b[2] = (test & 2) !=0;
      b[3] = (test & 4) !=0;
      b[4] = (test & 8) !=0;
      b[5] = (test & 16) !=0;
      b[6] = (test & 32) !=0;
      b[7] = (test & 64) !=0;
      b[8] = (test & 128) != 0;
      for(int i=1;i<=8;i++)
      {
        System.out.print(b[i]+" ");
      }
      System.out.println("\n");
    return;
}
```

with output when test is 0x1f:

```
true true true true true false false false
```

Comment: Still falses... What is interesting that this was working and boom

Comment: try if the minimum function demo above works with your "javac / java" command. If it dose, I suggest you check other parts in your code frame